# How to break Switch case when request inside case is done?

Tags: jquery, switch-statement, break

I have small piece of code in which there is a request inside one of the case of switch case statement.

```
var id;
switch(type){
    case 'type1':
        //some code
        break;

    case 'type2': case 'type3': case 'type4': 
        //some code 
        ajax.get('url', 'JSON', 
            function(response) {
            //callback for success  
                dosomething(response, id);
            },
        function(response) {
            //call back for failure
                dosomethingelse();
        }
          );
    break;
}
```

In case of type2 type3 type4, request is being send, but that case breaks before the getting the response. and since the variable "id" is changing on every switch call, by the time i get the response i have different value of id.

Can some how i break the case one i have received the response? I tried putting it inside, but that does not work, it throws some error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is async, meaning it doesnt wait for the call to finish to begin going thru the rest of the code.

wrap the ajax call in a anon function so you can preserver the id value

```
var id;


switch(type){
    case 'type1':
    //some code
    break;

    case 'type2': case 'type3': case 'type4': 
    //some code
    (function(id){
        ajax.get('url', 'JSON', 
            function(response) {
            //callback for success  
            dosomething(response, id);
            },
            function(response) {
                //call back for failure
                dosomethingelse();
            }
        );
     })(id);
    break;
}
```

Comment: I am calling the function dosomething() with the response of ajax call and one variable which changes everything the switch is called, so by the time i get the response, the variable has a different value.

Comment: As i understand it, you should enclose just the ajax request, not the switch statement

Comment: yea i wasnt thinking i was making the edit for that as you made the  comment :)